# React-Select drop-down menu change default text

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am currently using [React-Select](https://react-select.com/home) to create a dropdown menu. It's pretty simple code:

```
<Select className="dropdown" value={this.state.selectedOption} 
 options={this.state.options} onChange={this.handleQueryDropdown.bind(this)}/>
```

Which produces this:

[image: The React-Select Dropdown]

**My Question:** Is it possible to change the "*Select...*" to a different message? I searched on stack and the api, but couldn't find any examples.

Thanks!

Comment: what about `defaultValue` attribut?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use: `placeholder` property.

```
  <Select
    className="dropdown"
    value={this.state.selectedOption} 
    options={this.state.options}
    onChange={this.handleQueryDropdown.bind(this)}
    placeholder='Any String You Want'
  />
```

From: [props](https://react-select.com/props#prop-types)

Comment: Thanks! For some reason i didn't find that option

Comment: Did it work? it's totally fine, APIs can be hard to find sometimes.

Comment: Yup it worked. I'm currently waiting on the time limit to accept the answer to go away, then I'll accept it!

Comment: Great, then I'll pass to another question :devil_face:, I usually tend to fully provide help for one question at a time, thanks for being quick on responding!

Comment: Of course, thank you also for the quick response! :)